# NPM EJSONPARSE Error

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Every time i am trying to install anything i am getting this error, why?
reinstalled node.js many times still its same for any package.

```
    C:\Users\Kamlesh\cjbnf>npm install express --save
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Kamlesh\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express" "--save"
npm ERR! node v7.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9
npm ERR! file C:\Users\Kamlesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\array-flatten\1.1.1\package\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token 's' at 1:1
npm ERR! s0��[��}E?�
npm ERR! ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\Kamlesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\array-flatten\1.1.1\package\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kamlesh\cjbnf\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Try cleaning the NPM cache: `npm cache clean`

Comment: Ahh, Thanks its working now. New in this.